# Firebug returning odd error for one getElementById

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have the following lines of js

```
var select_container = "container_"+parts[2];
var get_container = document.getElementById(select_container);
```

The function this is part of is failing and when I look in firebug it returns get_container as undefined. I have checked select_container is the correct value and that there isn't a duplicate id on page.

This is called by an onclick event so I can't see waiting for the page to load being an issue (the result is same no matter how long I wait).

revelent html example:

```
<div id="container_0">
```

I'm stumped!

edit

This is all the Javascript from the parent functions

```
/*detects links in the form editor and uses them to adjust the layout*/
window.onload = function () {
    clickDetection();
} /*detect clicks on interesting links*/

function clickDetection() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("content");
    var dumbLinks = canvas.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < dumbLinks.length; i++) {
        dumbLinks[i].onclick = function () {
            clickRoute(this);
            return false
        };
    }
} /*reroute click behaviour to correct function*/

function clickRoute(link_object) {
    var linkId = link_object.getAttribute("id");
    var linkParts = linkId.split("_");
    if (linkParts[1] == "delete") {
        delete_route(linkParts);
    } else if (linkParts[1] == "new") {
        new_route(linkParts);
    }
}
function delete_route(parts) {
    alert(parts);
    if (parts[0] == "field") {
        var select_container = "container_" + parts[2];
        var get_container = document.getElementById(select_container);
        document.removeChild(get_container);
    } else if (parts[0] == "option") {
        alert("delete a option");
    }
}
```

full (typical) html (please note repeating sections have been cut for length and other details changed for secuity):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<!-- determines header content -->

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials" />
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="some.js"></script>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="bignavblock"><p><a href="removed">nav link</a></p></div>

<div class="bignavblock"><p><a href="removed">nav linke</a></p></div>

<div class="bignavblock"><p><a href="removed">nav link</a></p></div>

<div class="bignavblock"><p><a href="removed">nav link</a></p></div>

<div class="bignavblock"><p><a href="removed">nav link</a></p></div>

<div class="bignavblock"><p><a href="removed">nav link</a></p></div>

<div id="content">

<h1>screen name</h1>

<form method="post" action="#this">
<label for="summary">Select an item to edit:<br></label>
<select name="summary" id="summary">

<option value="generic">generic</option>
<option value="updated">updated</option>

</select>

<input type="submit" name="summary_select" value="Select">

</form>


<h2>screen name</h2>

<div id="container_7">
<form method="post" action="#this">
<fieldset><legend>existing segment</legend>

<p><a id="field_delete_7" href="#">Delete field</a></p>

<label for="name_7">Field Name</label><input type=text id="name_7" name="name" value="Colour"><br>

    <label for="type_7">Data type expected</label>   
     <select name="type" id="type_7">  

     <option value="name" >Name</option>
    <option value="email" >Email Address</option>
    <!-- cut for length -->


    </select>
    <p>Some text</p>

    <label for="option_7_0">Option Value</label><input type=text id="option_7_0" name="option_7_0" value="Red">
        <a id="option_delete_7_0" href="#">Delete option</a><br>

        <label for="option_7_1">Option Value</label><input type=text id="option_7_1" name="option_7_1" value="Green">
        <a id="option_delete_7_1" href="#">Delete option</a><br>

        <label for="option_7_2">Option Value</label><input type=text id="option_7_2" name="option_7_2" value="Blue">
        <a id="option_delete_7_2" href="#">Delete option</a><br>

        <a id="option_new_7" href="#">Add new option</a>

        <input type="submit" name="detail" value="Finish"></fieldset></form></div>

        <p><a id="field_new" href="#">Add new field</a></p>


</div>

<!-- determines footer content -->

footer content
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does firebug show your for the value of `select_container`? And what does it do if you enter `document.getElementById('container_0')` in the console?

Comment: what is parts and can you guarantee that parts[2] is what you are expecting? I would do a console.log("parts",parts[2]); and also print out select_container in your code and make certain that it is what you expect. I'm betting that for some value parts[2] is invalid and so the code can't find a matching id.

Comment: select_container returns values like container_0, container_1, container_2 ect. I have never seen any changes and parts is taken from hyperlinks generated by php with a very simple process. I can't see how it could ever produce incorrect data.

Comment: @Ian console returns <div id="container_0">

Comment: How could the console show `<div id="container_0">` for `select_container` if you're just doing `"container_"+parts[2]`?

Comment: @patrick parts[2] is a number added to the string. @Eineki working though the validation errors now. They are all empty action attributes and label for attributes not conected to form input controls.

Comment: Yes, I get that. Again, if you're doing `var select_container="container_"+parts[2];` then how can you get that result from logging `select_container` to the console? You should be getting something more like `container_0`.

Comment: @Patrick Ian asked me to use "container_0" not "container_"+parts[2] in the console. I didn't use the parts array to get the result.

Comment: He asked *"What does firebug show your for the value of select_container?"* The point is that it seems to work when you hardcode the number, so what do you get as a result of the concatenation. Please log `select_container` to the console.

Comment: Just use breakpoints and walk your function line-by-line, checking all relevant values. You'll get an answer.

Comment: @patrick. Sorry didn't see that part of the question. Assuming I fire the first link with an onclick event I get "current_0"

Comment: HTML is now valid. Problem is still peristing. Also the second line in the original post is the only breakpoint.

Comment: I assume you mean you get `container_0`, and not `current_0`.

Comment: @patrick. Ehh yes. Should edit that. But can't!

Comment: In that case, whatever the issue is, it doesn't seem to be included in the question. Can you give a broader picture of your code?

Comment: I posted an answer, but could you please post some HTML as well so we can have a full picture. Now that I look again, `document.removeChild()` may be alright.

Comment: ...actually, I was thinking of `document.body.remove...`. Doing `document.remove...` will fail. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
document.removeChild(get_container);
```

to this:

```
get_container.parentNode.removeChild(get_container);
```

or if the containers are a direct descendant of `body`, then you could do this:

```
document.body.removeChild(get_container);
```

Comment: No sorry - that doesn't seem to be addressing the problem code.

Comment: @YsoL8: When I change `docuent.removeChild(get_container);` to `get_container.parentNode.removeChild(get_container);` and click on the `Delete field` link, it works for me. [Here's a live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/67BgP/)

Comment: No. I've done this change to code you posted, and everything works. W/o that change my firebug returns ``Node was not found" code: "8''. Isn't your firebug version outdated?

Comment: OK - apologies. I hadn't actually tried the third suggestion as I didn't think that was the problem. And yes I haven't updated firebug in some time. Cheers for the help!